# Possibility of inserting many rows in to table with single database hit

Tags: java, database, oracle, insert

I came across this scenario where I have to insert some 100 rows into my table using the Java application that I support.

I do not want my application to hit the DB every time with the insert query to do this.

Can you suggest some idea for me to insert all those 100 rows in to that table with a single DB hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do [batch query processing](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/) for this purpose.